# Enforce "spaces" or "tabs" only in python files?

Tags: python, tabs, indentation, spaces

In Python, is there a mean to enforce the use of spaces or tabs indentation with a per file basis ?

Well, perhaps "enforce" is too strong, more like a "recommendation".

I keep receiving patch files with mixed indentation and this is annoying... (to say the least) Python itself can tell when there is a problem, but I am searching something to do that at the editor level, like it exists for the charset.

Edit : Ok, my question wasn't clear, I am asking this because I keep receiving corrections and patches in any mix of tab/space you can imagine. I am using Mercurial as a DVCS, perhaps something exists at this level ?

Comment: there should be a hook somewhere that all incoming files are run through.  You should add a tabs2spaces script there. Or just talk to the people sending you the patches - if the main script is using spaces then they are incorrect to be sending you patches with tabs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tim Peters has written a nifty script called [reindent.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py) which converts .py files to use 4-space indents and no tabs. It is available [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py), but check your distribution first -- it may have come bundled in an Examples or Tools directory. (On the latest LTS Ubuntu, it is provided by the `python2.7-examples` package.)

If you can set up a Mercurial hook you should be able to run all files through reindent.py.

By the way, if you are using unix, then your system may also have the `expand` (and `unexpand`) command, which convert all tabs to spaces (and spaces to tabs). However, in this case, I think `reindent.py` is the right tool.

Comment: +1, love reindent.  BTW, can you recommend s/thing similar for Javascript, HTML, CSS, ...?  Not semantically crucial, but in multiauthor projects doing a lot of those I find the idiosyncratic style mixes annoying -- and I do mostly use hg these days!-)

Comment: @Alex: Oh, how I would love to offer you something intelligent, but alas, I don't have a good suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [`tabnanny`](http://docs.python.org/library/tabnanny.html#module-tabnanny) module: — Detection of ambiguous indentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is something your editor should do for you. Most editors (try Notepad++ for example, it's free) will let you set whether hitting tab enters a tab character or a number of spaces. I'd recommend using two spaces instead of tab in all files (I find 4 is too much). Using spaces instead of tabs is better as it means that you can indent stuff using both the space & tab keys without worrying about messing up your files.

If you have files that have a mix it isn't hard to write your own script to convert tabs to spaces

Comment: The question was not about how to properly indent code the author is writing, but to fix patches that are sent from outside contributors.  Additionally, no need to write a script when tools like "expand" and "reindent.py" exist.

Answer (score 2):

As explicited in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), never mix tabs and space. However, a file with both may just run...
As it says there:

> ```
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only.  The
> second-most popular way is with tabs only.  Code indented with a mixture
> of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively.
> When invoking the Python command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues
> warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces.  When using -tt
> these warnings become errors.  These options are highly recommended!
> ```

the solution is therefore to use as a default:

```
python -t my_mixed_code.py
```

To answer at the editor level, this depends on the editor, please specify!

Comment: There is an editor directive to set then character encoding of the file, for example "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" to save text as utf-8. Perhaps there is something similar to set the tab width ?

Answer (score 0):

[Python PEP 8 standards](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommends that you always use 4 consecutive spaces to indicate indentation. You can use this python package called [reindent](https://pypi.org/project/reindent/) to convert tabs to spaces.

- `pip install reindent`
- `reindent file.py # or project_dir`